# Redux React Todo Application has no indication of error but doesn't work

Tags: redux

I'm following egghead.io Redux course by Dan.
However I've no idea why my todo app is not working. It doesn't output any error and any warning, just doesn't work.

Can you please give me some hint.

This is my jsbin.
https://jsbin.com/cozecip/33/edit?js,output

```
const todo = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      };
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state;
      }

      return {
        id: state.id,
        text: state.text,
        completed: !state.completed
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        todo(undefined, action)
      ];
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(t =>
        todo(t, action)
      );
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const visibilityFilter = (state = 'SHOW_ALL', action) =>
{
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER':
      return action.filter;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

const { combineReducers } = Redux;

const todoApp = combineReducers({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
});

const { createStore } = Redux;
const store = createStore(todoApp);

const { Component } = React;

const FilterLink = ({
    filter,
    currentFilter,
    children,
    onClick
}) => {
    if (filter === currentFilter){
      return <span>{children}</span>
    }

    return (
      <a href="#" onClick ={onClick}>{children}</a>
    );
};

const Todo = ({
  onClick,
  completed,
  text
}) => (
  <li
    onClick={onClick}
    style={{
      textDecoration:
        completed ?
          'line-through' :
          'none'
    }}
  >
    {text}
  </li>
);


const TodoList = ({
  todos,
  onTodoClick
}) => (
  <ul>
    {todos.map(todo =>
      <Todo
        key={todo.id}
        {...todo}
        onClick={() => onTodoClick(todo.id)}
      />
    )}
  </ul>
)

const AddTodo = ({
  onAddClick
}) => {
  let input;

  return (
    <div>
    <input ref={node => {
       input = node;
    }} />
    <button onClick={() => {
      onAddClick(input.value)
      input.value = '';
    }}>
    Add Todo
    </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const Footer = ({
  visibilityFilter,
  onFilterClick
}) => (
        <p>
          Show:
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_ALL'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
            onClick={onFilterClick}>
              All
          </FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_ACTIVE'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
            onClick={onFilterClick}>
            Active
          </FilterLink>
          {' '}
          <FilterLink
            filter='SHOW_COMPLETED'
            currentFilter={visibilityFilter}
            onClick={onFilterClick}>
            Completed
          </FilterLink>
        </p>

)

const getVisibleTodos = (todos, filter) => {
  switch(filter){
    case 'SHOW_ALL':
      return todos;
    case 'SHOW_COMPLETED':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed);
    case 'SHOW_ACTIVE':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed);
    default:
      return todos;
  }
}

let nextTodoId = 0;
const TodoApp = ({
  todos,
  visibilityFilter
}) => {
  return (
  <div>
    <AddTodo
      onAddClick={
        text =>
          store.dispatch({
            type: 'ADD_TODO',
            text: this.input.value,
            id: nextTodoId++
           })
      }
    />
    <TodoList
      todos={
        getVisibleTodos(
               todos,
               visibilityFilter
        )
      }
      onTodoClick={id =>
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'TOGGLE_TODO',
          id
         })
      }
    />
    <Footer
      visibilityFilter={visibilityFilter}
      onFilterClick={filter =>
        store.dispatch({
          type: 'SET_VISIBILITY_FILTER',
          filter
        })
      }
    />
 </div>
 );
}

const render = () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    // Render the TodoApp Component to the <div> with id 'root'
    <TodoApp
      {...store.getState()}
    />,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

store.subscribe(render);
render();
```

Comment: check the console there's an error saying that redux is not defined , so in other words you forgot to add the redux library

Comment: can't see any error on the console.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/help/adding-custom-libraries and if you dont wanna bother copy your code and past it to this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ypnnkjk7/3/ it will be easier

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the correct ID in index.js
it should look like this.
document.getElementById('your div id from index.html should go here')

Comment: do you still have the issue?

Comment: Yes James, i still have the issue, and i gave up on this.

Comment: I got the same bug, might be something wrong with jsbin